# Externalizing Grails Datasource configuration

Tags: configuration, grails, datasource, external, credentials

Grails 1.x allows using external configuration files by setting the **grails.config.locations** directive. Is there a similar approach available for externalizing the database configuration in Datasource.groovy (without setting up JNDI)?

It would prove helpful to be able to configure DB credentials in a simple configuration file outside the application.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use a properties file specified in the grails.config.locations as a way to externalize the datasource configuration.  Below is how I typically set up a Grails project:

In my DataSource.groovy I specify this for the production environment:

```
  ....
  ....
  production {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        driverClassName = "com.myorg.jdbcDriverNotExists"
        url = ""
        username = ""
        password = ""
    }
  }
  ....
  ....
```

I specify an external properties file in my Config.groovy:

```
grails.config.locations = [ "classpath:app-config.properties"]
```

In the properties file (stored in grails-app/conf/) I specify the actual datasource info:

```
dataSource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
dataSource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:sid
dataSource.username=sa
dataSource.password=secret
```

I also use the properties file as a way to override other values that are in Config.groovy.  When the app is deployed, if I have to modify the datasource info I just edit the /WEB-INF/classes/app-config.properties file and restart.

Comment: This looks like just what I was after! Thank you for your clear and concise answer, John :)

Comment: This looks like a great solution, except you do have edits after an upgrade. For externalizing the configuration see
http://blog.zmok.net/articles/2009/04/22/playing-with-grails-application-configuration

Comment: As Brad pointed out, this isn't a viable solution for deploying a war.  The link he posts is a better answer.

Comment: As neomusashi mentioned, I don't think this is a good solution. Usually you want to have the application configuration outside the application package and source code.

Comment: one small question, if I don't specify "properties" for the datasource (the info of reconnect,...) will they still be taken from datasource.groovy ?

Answer (score 25):

The answer above does not really externalize configuration. He is close, but the configuration is still residing in the application.
I would use a JVM environment var on startup of the application/server to point to a location outside the application where the external configuration resides. Read out the environment var in the config.groovy file and use it get the external configuration file. Something like this:

```
def extConfig = System.properties.getProperty('ENVVAR');
grails.config.locations = [ "file:${extConfig}/${appName}-config.groovy"]
```

Answer (score 1):

For me this doesn't work. To get an environment variable.

**Better use :**

```
System.getenv().get("ENVVAR").toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the configuration file location as following in Config.groovy file

```
grails.config.locations = [
            "file:/yourDirectory/${appName}/${Environment.current.name}-datasource.properties",
            "file:/yourDirectory/${appName}/${Environment.current.name}-config.groovy",
            "classpath:${appName}-${Environment.current.name}-datasource.properties",
            "classpath:${appName}-${Environment.current.name}-config.groovy"
    ]
```

And put all the details about datasource and other config values in your appropriate file. Hence you can externalize the configuration and need not restart to change values.