# Grails: subfolder is ignored

Tags: grails

I have a grails app running on a URL something like -

> http://{ip address}/appName

Now I am trying to have a sub-folder of my domain pointing to that app server.
Something like -

> http://www.example.com/subfolder/appName => http://{ip address}/appName

When I load the url with subfolder the grails app responds properly and redirects to the first page of the app (as expected). But the problem is - all other URL's in the page (controllers, css, image files, etc.) ignores the "subfolder" at the end of the URL.

Like, instead of trying to point to

> http://www.example.com/**social**/appName/{controllerName}
>
> http://www.example.com/**social**/appName/{cssFileName}
>
> etc

Everything points to

> http://www.example.com/appName/{controllerName}
>
> http://www.example.com/appName/{cssFileName}
>
> etc

I have tried modifying grails.serverURL and grails.app.context. But still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
grails.app.context="/social"
```

See also: [grails 2.0 - correct use of serverURL for production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200949/grails-2-0-correct-use-of-serverurl-for-production)