# grails - datasources plugin, domainClass is not mapped

Tags: grails

Working with the datasources plugin using grails 1.3.6 (will upgrade soon) I get this error when rendering a taglib

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: DomainA is not mapped
```

These are the databases (both are postgresql and are located in the same server):

```
database A
    schema x
        table domain_a
        table domain_b
database B
    schema x
        table DomainA
        table DomainB
```

These are my mappings:

```
class domainA { // Domain A is defined in a plugin
    mapping(table: "x.domain_a")
}

class domainB {
    mapping(table: "x.domain_b")
}
```

What I want is domainA to be mapped in Database A and domainB to be mapped in Database B.

I'm using grails.config.locations in Config.groovy for Database A and Datasources.groovy for Database B with this config:

```
datasource(name: 'databaseB') {
    driverClassName('org.postgresql.Driver')
    url('jdbc:postgresql://host/databaseB')
    username('user')
    password('****')
    domainClasses(['DomainB'])
    readOnly(true)
    dialect("org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect")
    pooled(true)
    environments(['development', 'test'])
}
```

I don't get what seems to be the problem

Has anyone had this trouble, Is there a workaround I could use? Maybe an upgrade to grails 2 could help?

Comment: Try domainClasses([DomainA]) and domainClasses([DomainB]) and import  class in the file instead of using string.

Comment: I've already done that, in fact string is the other attempt i tried. Before it was like this: domainClasses([package.DomainB])

Comment: I use multiple datasources in Grails 2.x with no problems, but I don't need to use plugin + external configuration for that. You should check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970133/externalizing-grails-datasource-configuration . External datasource configuration requires a trick

Comment: Guess I'll try Grails 2 after all, guess it's something with the main datasource's configuration and its domains.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I kinda solved creating another datasource with database A (the main one) in datasources.groovy and including domainA (and all other domains related) in there, like this:

```
import package.DomainA

datasource(name: 'databaseA') {
    driverClassName('org.postgresql.Driver')
    url('jdbc:postgresql://host/databaseA')
    username('user')
    password('***')
    domainClasses([DomainA, OtherDomains])
}
```