# Grails - Cannot read externalized configuration values

Tags: tomcat, grails, environment-variables, production-environment

I am developing a grails application. I want to **externalize** certain configuration values, so they can be specified on **server startup**.

In **development** I run the application using the following command to run the application

> grails prod run-app -Dmy.property="secret"

At **runtime** I want to read the value in my controller using the following code

> String myVal= System.getProperty("my.property")

When I check the value of myVal it is always **null**. I just want to be able to read the value of my.value consistently, pointers appreciated.

**Note**: I do not want to store values in Config.groovy.  I have also tried System.getenv().get("my.property"), but that does not work either.

I have also referred to [Externalizing Grails Datasource configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970133/externalizing-grails-datasource-configuration).

Comment: You should take a look to [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24271680/615274

Answer (score 1):

Well, the blog which you pointed out is correct. Below is what you could add in your config file.

```
if (new File("${userHome}/.${appName}/${appName}-config.groovy").exists()) {
  grails.config.locations = ["file:${userHome}/.${appName}/${appName}-config.groovy"]
  println("loading configuration from: :${grails.config.locations}")
} else {
    println("No external configuration file defined.....")
}
```

Add this to right at the top of your config.groovy file. The you could put your external config file as below.

Assuming my appname is "test"

```
/usr/home/myhome/.test/test-config.groovy
```

For dynamic reloading of config during changes in external config file you could look at this plugin: http://grails.org/plugin/external-config-reload

Comment: I need to be able to deploy a single war file and not recompile every time values change..with your suggestion - it seems I may have to recompile again? Let me know if my assumptions are incorrect. Thx

Comment: Added a link in my answer for dynamic loading of config.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the order of the parameters. All the "-D" params are java parameters so, if you check the java command that is running background does not recognize those params at the end.
In short, what you should do is:

```
grails -Dmy.property="secret" prod run-app
```

Comment: That did not work,usually command line parameters are mostly order agnostic. Can you point me to a resource where you saw the ordering etc. matters? Thx